# How to structure nested React Router to avoid error: redirect to the same route you're on

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For the layout of my site, I want every content page to have the same padding, but I want the landing page component to have no such padding. To accomplish this I use a nested React Router; the outer Switch checks if it should display the landing page. If not, it renders a ContentPage, which places an outer padded div and then uses another React Router to load in the appropriate content. I have a Redirect case in the inner Switch so that if the user types in a nonexistent url, it will redirect them to the landing page. However, bad urls now give me this error:

```
You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"
```

Here's my outer Router:

```
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>

        <Route path="/" render={(props) => (
          <ContentPage isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} passwordHash={this.state.passwordHash} {...props} />
        )} />
      </Switch>
```

And here's my inner router:

```
class ContentPage extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <div className="content" style={{padding: "36px"}}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/logIn" component={LogIn}/>
            <Redirect to="/"/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I get the error when I try to go to a bad url like "/asdfasdf". It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, since the redirect should be from the random URL to "/".

If it's generally bad practice to have nested routers, I'm also open to any other method of having padding around all pages except for the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), there's an example how nested routing is implemented. Generally speaking, you **should not** nest routers. You should place your `<Route />`s inside **single** router `<BrowserRouter />` component.

I made a simple example based on the official documentation just to demonstrate how does nesting and redirects look like:

https://codesandbox.io/s/yw47150lvx

In the example, there's a couple of different parent routes:

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
 <Route path="/about" component={About} />
 <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
 <Redirect to="/" />;
```

`<Redirect to="/"` is used in case the given URL does not match any routes.

Within route `<Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />` (`Topics` component) there are some other routes:

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
<Route
  exact
  path={match.path}
  render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
/>
```

I used `match.path` prop which is automatically passed to `Topics` to construct **nested** URL path, e.g.: `/topics/1`, `topics/2` for the first nested route and `topics/` for the second nested routes (it is designed to indicate that there's no specific topic selected)

Comment: Hey, it looks like your example doesn't have nested Routes--there's just one <Router>. My particular question is how you would write your example if you wanted to have the same padding around the About component and the Topic component (and all other components besides Home)

Comment: @rampatowl You should use the single `<Router />` (it's actually `<BrowserRouter />` -- I did import like `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'` in my example) component and combine multiple `<Route />`s inside it

Comment: @rampatowl I've updated my answer with more clear explanation